# getting out of a loop in C

Tags: c, for-loop, while-loop

I am trying to get out of a `while loop` using C, but using breaks, returns or changing the while condition are not working.

Basically, I want to know why in the last `else if`, when I state `back = true` my code keeps entering the `for`.

I would expect an output like: `enter1, enter1, enter1, enter1, enter2`.

Instead, the output is something like `enter1, enter1, enter1, enter2, enter2, enter2, enter1, enter1, enter1`....

This is my code work:

```
void SolveMap8(Core* core_building, Building* new, Stack* solve, bool goingBack){
  Core* coreBuilding = core_building;
  Building* first = new -> linked[0];
  Building* next  = NULL;
  bool back = goingBack;
  while (back == false) {
    for (int i = 0; i < (first -> zone -> building_count); i++) {
      if (first ->  zone -> buildings[i] != NULL) {
        if (first != first ->  zone -> buildings[i]) {
          next  = first ->  zone -> buildings[i];
          if(next -> color == coreBuilding -> buildings[0] -> color && !city_client_is_taken(next)) {
            puts("enter0");
            Building_Pair* newPair = Building_Tuple_Create(first, next);
            stack_push(solve, newPair);
            city_client_link(first, next);
            break;
          }
          else if(!city_client_is_taken(next)) {
            if (city_client_is_blank(next)) {
              if (!(next -> cored)) {
                puts("enter1");
                Building_Pair* newPair = Building_Tuple_Create(first, next);
                stack_push(solve, newPair);
                city_client_link(first, next);
                SolveMap8(coreBuilding, next, solve, false);
              }
            }
          }
          else if (city_client_is_taken(next)) {
            if (i == first -> zone -> building_count - 1) {
                puts("enter2");
                back = true;
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The test `back == false` won't be done until your `for` loop terminates.  Maybe in your `if(city_client_is_taken(next))` branch, you wanted to say `back = true` and then `break;`?

Comment: The `if (i == first -> zone -> building_count - 1) ` condition before setting `back = true` means this will only happen on the last iteration of the `for` loop, so a `break` shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: Try printing the value of `i` on each iteration of the `for` loop, and print the value of `first->zone->building_count` before the loop.  That should give you a better idea of what's going on.

Comment: Is it possible that `SolveMap8` is being called more than once?

Comment: Note that the arrow `->` and dot `.` operators bind very tightly and should not be separated from their operands by spaces.  That is, your line `if(next -> color == coreBuilding -> buildings[0] -> color && !city_client_is_taken(next))` should be `if (next->color == coreBuilding->buildings[0]->color && !city_client_is_taken(next))` (note the space after the keyword, too).

Comment: indent width, 2 spaces, is not wide enough to be visible with variable width fonts.  Suggest using 4 spaces.

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding by us humans: separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via a blank line

Comment: this line: `while (back == false)` would be much better written as: `while ( !back)`

Comment: the posted code does nothing if the passed in parameter:` goingback` is `true`.   Why call the function at all if `goingback` is `true`?

Comment: following this line: `back = true;`  there needs to be a line to exit the inner `for()` loop.  Suggest: `break;`

Comment: this line: `else if (city_client_is_taken(next))` can be reduced to: `else`

Comment: the function: `SolveMap8()`  is recursively called.  the function has only one way to exit.  so the recursion could go quite deep before beginning to unwind.  So an effective exit strategy for unwinding needs to be implemented.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update** Sorry, missed the recursion. In that case your problem has nothing to do with a missing break statement, but that you are trying to escape from a for loop at a different scope than you are currently in. You will need special logic to handle a global "done" condition. Perhaps something like this:

```
void process(Core* core, bool& done) {
    for (int i = 0; i < core->size() && !done; ++i) {
        if (!core[i]->is_taken()) {
            process(core[i], done);
        } else if (core[i]->is_taken() {
            // done procesing
            done = true;
        }
    }
}

// use via
bool done = false;
process(myCore, done);
```

In the version you have, the goingBack flag is passed by value, so every function gets its own copy and there is no way to pass the value of back to the parent in the recursive call chain. In my code above, done is passed as a reference, so changing the value at some point in the recursion chain will make it visible at parent scope (because the scope of the variable is outside the function itself). Hope this is more helpful.

Comment: It looks like this isn't the problem, since that code is only executed on the final iteration of the `for` loop.  In that case, adding a `break` wouldn't matter.

Comment: I jus add a `break;`after the `back = true`at the end and the output is still something like `enter1, enter1, enter1, enter2, enter2, enter2, enter1, enter2, enter1`.

Comment: Beware there is a recursion, so it is not necessarily the last line in the code.